# Test if Parent's Wow64 Redirection is Disabled

Tags: winapi, wow64

How do you test if your parent process has disabled WOW64 redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referring to WOW64 File System redirection, I doubt you can test if the parent process has disabled WOW64 FS Redirection.

The reason I say this is because WOW64 FS redirection not disabled at the process level but at the thread level. And a child process has no concept of the thread in the parent process that spawned it.